# How to Integrate Salesforce with RentalResult?

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, callout, website-integration

How to authenticate Salesforce with RentalResult? Is there any document API? I have tried the following link but no API (endpoint) is found to authenticate the salesforce with RetalResult. Please give me any suggestion to solve the issue.

http://www.wynnesystems.com/assets/downloads/Wynne_Systems_Integration_White_Paper_-_RentalResult.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When I checked your shared document I found that there are some end points provided in that

[image]

So you might need to read that document again also it will be better if you ask from there support because they can easily give you REST endpoints or WSDL (Whichever is required based on requirement)